# How to use a name different from "Figure" in the caption?

Tags: cross-referencing, captions, cleveref

I'm writing a document with many tables and figures.

This is a reproducible piece of my document.
(With LuaTeX, but plain LaTeX is OK too).

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[capitalise,noabbrev]{cleveref}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} 
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
%\counterwithin{figure}{subsection}
\usepackage[skip=5pt]{caption}  %, margin=2em   ,labelfont=it,  , textfont=it
\captionsetup{font=small, labelfont=bf} %,format=hang
\addtolength{\footnotesep}{5mm}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
\cref{fig:esquema1} summarizes the process

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.95\linewidth]{esquema1}
    \caption{My caption.}
    \label{fig:esquema1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I'd like that some captions instead of "Figure 1" were automatically called "Diagram 1", both below the figure and when referenced from the document.

How can tell LaTeX to do it?

I've read something like

```
%\captionsetup[figure]{name={Fig.}}
```

will change the name, but it will do it for all Figures.

I would like to keep that name for figures (real pictures) but add a new "Diagram" name for other (diagrams made with tikz and other).

Comment: Please fix your document by adding `graphicx` and `cleveref` package loading, `graphicx` with `demo` option, otherwise reproducible is doubtful ;-)

Comment: `float` includes `\newfloat` command to declare new floats, why not use it to distinguish `figures` from `diagram`?

Comment: @Ignasi Could you post an example and explain the advantages of "\newfloat" over Christian's methods, please?

Comment: @skan If you just want to use `diagram` occasionally, Chirstian's method is the easiest. I've tested with `newfloat` and table of figures doesn't look good.

Comment: @Ignasi: The idea with `newfloat` is good, in my point of view, but it will introduce a new `\listof...` macro (as far as I know), so diagram and figure are not merged in `LoF`. Perhaps `\let\l@diagram\l@figure` will improve the look of `LoF` which look bad as you reported?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a version suitable for some few occurences of such `diagram` caption:

1. Define a counter named `diagram` (for example) that shares the same value as `figure`, with `\newaliascnt` from `aliascnt` package.
2. Say `\captionsetup{name={Diag.}}` within the figure environment that should have `Diag.` as caption lead-in.
3. Define `\crefname` and `\Crefname` for `diagram` counter.
4. Say `\label[diagram]{...}` in order to make `cleveref` aware that the `diagram` counter should be referenced and not `figure`.

---

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{aliascnt}
\newaliascnt{diagram}{figure}

%\counterwithin{figure}{subsection}
\usepackage[skip=5pt]{caption}  %, margin=2em   ,labelfont=it,  , textfont=it
\captionsetup{font=small, labelfont=bf} %,format=hang
\addtolength{\footnotesep}{5mm}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\crefname{diagram}{diagram}{diagrams}
\Crefname{diagram}{Diagram}{Diagrams}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
\cref{fig:esquema1} summarizes the process

\begin{figure}[h]
    \captionsetup{name={Diag.}} 
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.95\linewidth]{esquema1}
    \caption{My caption.}
    \label[diagram]{fig:esquema1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What if I want to share the same counter for diagrams and figures or us different ones?